# Negative time duration in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with two columns: Actual Time and Promised Time (representing the actual and promised start times of some process).

For example:

```
import pandas as pd
example_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Actual Time', 'Promised Time'],
                 data = [
                     ('2016-6-10 9:00', '2016-6-10 9:00'),
                     ('2016-6-15 8:52', '2016-6-15 9:52'),
                     ('2016-6-19 8:54', '2016-6-19 9:02')]).applymap(pd.Timestamp)
```

So as we can see, `sometimes Actual Time = Promised Time`, but there are also cases where `Actual Time < Promised Time`.

I defined a column that shows the difference between these two columns (`example_df['Actual Time']-example_df['Promised Time']`), but the problem is that for the third row it returned `-1 day +23:52:00` instead of `- 00:08:00`.

Comment: can you reformat your data? It's hard to read this way.. are there multiple rows or is this a single row?

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: I've suggested an edit to replace your example data with code that generates it. Know that if you use columns with spaces, it's hard to use `pd.read_clipboard()` to copy your data. To learn more, please visit this great question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: So you want absolute values, no  `-00:08:00` ? Then please change answer, because question is how change `-1 day +23:52:00` to `- 00:08:00`  and accepting answer change to `00:08:00`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your dataframe already in `datetime` dtype. `abs` works just fine

Without `abs`

```
df['Actual Time'] - df['Promised Time']

Out[526]:
0            00:00:00
1   -1 days +23:00:00
2   -1 days +23:52:00
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

With `abs`

```
abs(df['Promised Time'] - df['Actual Time'])

Out[529]:
0   00:00:00
1   01:00:00
2   00:08:00
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Answer (score 2):

**Sample**:

```
print (df)
       Actual Time   Promised Time
0   2016-6-10 9:00  2016-6-10 9:00
1  2016-6-15 10:52  2016-6-15 9:52 <- changed datetimes
2   2016-6-19 8:54  2016-6-19 9:02

def format_timedelta(x):
    ts = x.total_seconds()
    if ts >= 0:
        hours, remainder = divmod(ts, 3600)
        minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)
        return ('{}:{:02d}:{:02d}').format(int(hours), int(minutes), int(seconds)) 
    else:
        hours, remainder = divmod(-ts, 3600)
        minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)
        return ('-{}:{:02d}:{:02d}').format(int(hours), int(minutes), int(seconds))
```

First create `datetime`s:

```
df['Actual Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Actual Time'])
df['Promised Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Promised Time'])
```

And then timedeltas:

```
df['diff'] = (df['Actual Time'] - df['Promised Time'])
```

If convert negative timedeltas to seconds by [`Series.dt.total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html) it working nice:

```
df['diff1'] = df['diff'].dt.total_seconds()
```

But if want negative timedeltas in string representation it is possible with custom function, because `strftime` for timedeltas is not yet implemented:

```
df['diff2'] = df['diff'].apply(format_timedelta)
print (df)
          Actual Time       Promised Time              diff   diff1     diff2
0 2016-06-10 09:00:00 2016-06-10 09:00:00          00:00:00     0.0   0:00:00
1 2016-06-15 10:52:00 2016-06-15 09:52:00          01:00:00  3600.0   1:00:00
2 2016-06-19 08:54:00 2016-06-19 09:02:00 -1 days +23:52:00  -480.0  -0:08:00
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference result is `timedelta` type which by default is in `ns` format.

You need to change the type of your result to you desired format:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame(data={
'Actual Time':['2016-6-10 9:00','2016-6-15 8:52','2016-6-19 8:54'],
'Promised Time':['2016-6-10 9:00','2016-6-15 9:52','2016-6-19 9:02']
},dtype='datetime64[ns]')

# here you need to add the `astype` part and to determine the unit you want
df['diff']=(df['Actual Time']-df['Promised Time']).astype('timedelta64[m]')
```